# How to duplicate values in Django formsets

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there a way to duplicate values during user input such that if a certain field is typed in the initial form, this value will be the default for the extra forms?
An example could be something like:

If I'm borrowing multiple books using the model below:

```
class Borrow(Model.models):
    library_card = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book')

class Book(Model.models):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I'd want my formset to have multiple Borrow transactions but the library_card input only has to be typed once.
Any tips on how I should go about this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you pretend to deal with this forms? I mean, do you want to display it sequentially after submitting one another (in that case use 'initial') or all at once (maybe some js)?

Comment: It would be great to have it all at once. Do you have any tips on how to use js with this? I've come across the jquery-formset.js plugin but I'm still wrapping my head around it. Will it be okay if you show a sample implementation? Thanks!

Comment: I have none experience whatsoever with it, sorry mate.
Maybe you should include it on your question thou, it will affect your answers.